# How to restrict HTML range slider from moving beyond a range

Tags: html, jquery, rangeslider

I'm using a range slider with range `0` to `100` and the current value is set to max.

My objective is that I have a limiting value of `50` so that the slider could be moved between `50` and `100` and not `0` to `50`. I have setup a jQuery handler as below, however I'm still able to move backwards from `50`.

Is there a way to prevent the slider from going backwards from `50`?

```js
$(document).on("input change", "#range", function() {
  var scrolled_value = $(this).val();
  var limiting_value = 50;

  if (scrolled_value <= limitng_value)
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="range" type="range" name="range" min="0" value="100" max="100" />
```

Comment: `limitng_value` you have a typo here in your if.

Comment: Can you not just change the `min` attribute to `50` through JS when required?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That will cause the slider to start at 50 too. The OP want the slider to start at 0 but not be able to slide it below 50.

Comment: @cloned sorry that was my typing mistake. That wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the value in the `change` event to stop it going below that value:

```
  if (scrolled_value <= limiting_value)
    $(this).val(limiting_value);
```

Giving an updated snippet (with as few changes as possible to the original):

```js
$(document).on("input change", "#range", function() {
  var scrolled_value = $(this).val();
  var limiting_value = 50;

  if (scrolled_value <= limiting_value)
    $(this).val(limiting_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="range" type="range" name="range" min="0" value="100" max="100" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this issue by setting the sliders value to 50 when it's below 50, like shown below:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const sliderLimit = 50;


input.addEventListener("input", () => {
  if (input.value < sliderLimit)
    input.value = sliderLimit;
})
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" value="100" max="100" />
```

Comment: OP's question was about **range** input & **jQuery**... not native DOM & text input... although similar, but still, better stick to OP's setup.

Comment: I am not to familiar with jquery, if you are, may I ask you to preform an edit @vsync - thanks

Answer (score -1):

Minimal solution using *jQuery* (like OP) while also limiting the value on *first-render*

```js
$('input').on("input change", function() {
  if (this.value > 50 )
    this.value = 50
}).trigger('change')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" min="0" value="100" max="100" />
```

By the way, I've created a beautiful CSS-only range slider:
https://github.com/yairEO/ui-range